# Binding ComboBox (source) with Buttons not working properly.

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Hello I am binding 16 buttons to combobox, but I have problem that it works as it should only when window is loaded, then when i pick new color from ComboBox, background of buttons don't change.

This is how I am binding (Shape1Color is said combobox):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Shape1.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            Binding btnbinding = new Binding();
            btnbinding.Converter = new ButtonColorConverter();
            btnbinding.Source = Shape1Color.SelectedItem;
            btnbinding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true;
           (Shape1.Children[i] as Button).SetBinding(Button.BackgroundProperty, btnbinding);

        }
```

So it only works when window loads, but then when i choose new item from combobox it doesn't enter my converter and I don't know why.

Comment: Why the binding have SelectedItem as Source and not as Path? I would probably have the source to Shape1Color and Path to SelectedItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use `Shape1Color` as binding `Source` and set `SelectedItem` as `Path` for  binding

```
Binding btnbinding = new Binding();
btnbinding.Converter = new ButtonColorConverter();
btnbinding.Source = Shape1Color;
btnbinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem");
btnbinding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true;
```

setting `btnbinding.Source = Shape1Color.SelectedItem;` works but only once. It doesn't change when `SelectedItem` changes